# how to exclude the elements inside a div from the click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a jquery function doing the following :

- if I click everywhere inside the div (but elements inside this div), the code is executed .
- if I click in an html element inside this div , noting happens .

Comment: You can check, if `e.target` has the same `id` as your `div` which is allowed to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test if the clicked target is `this`. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBC43/

```
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this) return;
    alert('div clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The event is lopped through the element, until a element with a click element is found. 
Solutions:

1. Test if the target element is the same as the delegateTarget
2. You set the event of the inner elements to a empty function

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (i try to find parent div with your class):

```
<div class='foobar'>
    <span>child1</span>
    <span>child2</span>
</div>
<span>child3</span>

<script>
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
    var testelem = $(e.target);
    while (testelem != undefined && !testelem.hasClass('foobar')){
        testelem = testelem.parent();
    }

    if (testelem != undefined && testelem.hasClass('foobar')) {
        alert('code');
    }
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eaVzx/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target !== this) return;
        alert("inside a div");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tagName` dom property to get current target element name.

[**TagName:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) Returns the name of the element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv" style='display:inline-block; width:300px;'><span style='display:inline-block;'>Hello Click here</span><br /><span style='display:inline-block;'>Click here</span></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myDiv').click(function (e) {        
    if (e.target.tagName == "DIV") { 
       alert('Clicked on Div');
    }
    else{
       alert('Clicked on Inner Element');
    }
 });
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq6aB/1/)

OR also use `nodeName` property to get current element.

[**NodeName:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName) Returns the name of the current node as a string.

[Try in fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq6aB/2/)